# How to close cmd after LabVIEW code executes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, labview

When I am running batch file through LabVIEW by using System Exec.vi, two cmd windows are appearing. The second one executes command of the batch file and closes after that, while the first one doesn't close. I have tried to use [this solution](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P7lUSAS), but it doesn't work. Is there any way to close that first cmd ?

[image: LabVIEW code to run external .batch file]

[image: cmd windows]

P.S. If I run batch file not through LabVIEW, but just by double clicking on it, two cmd windows close after execution

Comment: Why do you use the `start` command? and why do you provide the batch file path as an argument to itself (check the finally built command line passed to "System Exec.vi")? If you do not want to change any of that, try to append `^& exit` to the command line...

Comment: Dear @aschipfl thank you for reply. Actually that is the way to execute external file by using System Exec.vi according to [this link](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/how-to-run-exe-file-by-labview/m-p/303952/highlight/true#M158352) (see comment of  WNM)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but I think you've misunderstood the directions given at that link. The batch file should contain the executable and its options, but you just pass the batch file to the System Exec VI. I'm guessing what's happening here is the batch file is getting called twice, and some process that the first call depends on is getting hijacked by the second call, so that when the process ends, the second call gets notified and stops itself, but the first call is left hanging. Or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I do not just pass the path of the batch file to the system, but I tell the system to execute the batch file, I think they are different actions. And I have already found the solution, I just need to write "^& exit" after [cmd /x /r start "%s" "%s"], where "%s" is the batch file path.

Is there any other way to run external file through LabVIEW? if yes, it would be fine if you share to info.

Comment: Got it. Glad you have a fix! I want to say there's another way to do it, but I've always used System Exec, so I'm not sure.

Comment: You should be able to just give a command line of "<path to batch file>\sp_svc.bat.bat". Leave the "cmd.exe" out of it.

Comment: I don't know why, but in my case the way you mentioned above doesn't work. It returns empty cmd window